# Consistency of MLE for $\theta$ where $f(x \mid \theta) = \frac{2x}{\theta^2}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, order-statistics

Let  $X= (X_1,...,X_n)$ be a random sample having PDF $f(x \mid \theta) = \frac{2x}{\theta^2}, 0 \le x \le \theta, \theta > 0$.

Find the MLE of $\theta $and show it is consistent.

I found the MLE using the likelihood function $L(\theta) = \frac{2^n}{\theta^{2n}}\Pi x_i1\{x_i \le \theta\}  $

To get that the MLE will be $\hat{\theta} = \max X_i$. This gives that we will be working with order statistics so $\hat{\theta} := Y_n$ will have pdf $nf(x)[F(x)]^{n-1}$ which turns out to be $\displaystyle \frac{2nx^{2n}}{\theta^{2n}}$.

To show consistency we need to show $Y_n$ converges to $\theta$ in probability so I have been working with:

let $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and $\displaystyle P(\theta - \epsilon < Y_n < \theta) = \int_{\theta-\epsilon}^\theta \frac{2n}{\theta^{2n}}x^{2n}dx = \frac{2n}{\theta^{2n}(2n+1)}\bigg (\theta^{2n+1} - (\theta-\epsilon)^{2n+1} \bigg)$

Which needs to go to zero as $n$ goes to infinity but that is not what I am getting.  EDIT: This probability to should going to $1$. I made a mistake as pointed out below.

Am I making a mistake in calculating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct density for the maximum order statistic $\hat \theta = X_{(n)}$ is, by your own formula, $$f_{\hat \theta} (x) = n f(x) (F(x))^{n-1} = n \cdot \frac{2x}{\theta^2} \cdot \left(\frac{x^2}{\theta^2}\right)^{n-1} = \frac{2n x^{2n-1}}{\theta^{2n}}.$$  Therefore, $$\Pr[\theta - \epsilon < \hat \theta < \theta] = 1 - (1 - \epsilon/\theta)^{2n}.$$  For any $\epsilon \in (0, \theta)$, $0 < 1 - \epsilon/\theta < 1$, hence the limiting probability is $1$ as $n \to \infty$.  But this is exactly what you want; you do not want this probability to tend to $0$ as you claim.  You seem to be confused about what constitutes convergence in probability as it applies to this question.  Formally, we say that $\hat \theta \to \theta$ in probability if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr[|\hat \theta - \theta| > \epsilon] = 0.$$  Note the direction of the inequality.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I was confusing the directions of the inequality along with whether the probability should go to 1 or 0. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Letting the sequence

$$Z_n=Max(X_i)$$

it is evident that

$$Z_{n+1}=Max(Z_n; X_{n+1})\geq Z_n$$

That means the sequence is monotone (non decreasing) and upper bounded in $Z_n=\theta$

Thus $Z_n$ converges a.s. to $\theta$

Comment: Are you treating $Z_n$ as a sequence of real numbers?

Comment: as a sequence of random variables bounded in $[0;\theta ]$

Comment: What is this theorem?

Comment: A sequence can be increasing and bounded above by some value $\theta$ but converge to some value less than $\theta$, so I don’t see how this helps.

Comment: as per my knowledge (I know that my knowledge is very basic as I am an accountant and not a mathematician) when a sequence is monotone and bounded it converges a.s, in probability and in Law to some rv, say X, In this case it seems to me that the only  possible value of convergence is exactly $\theta$ as shown in the above proof. I do not think that this sequence can converve a.s. to a different value. Am I wrong?

Comment: As I have never seen this before, I ask you again to cite the relevant result.